# What is the alternative of PMG (Permanent Magnet Generator) in a Horizontal Axis Wind Turbine?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I need to make a report about a HAWT (Horizontal Axis Wind Turbine) and list the parts with their costs, but as a Permanent Magnet Generator is a costly thing so what can I use in alternative of this to make the turbine less expensive?

P.S. Due to the short time, I didn't do any kind of research on this PMG part's alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Look up automotive generators. These have a field winding instead of permanent magnets. They require a small amount of electricity to energize the field winding before it will generate electricity. Once the field winding is energized and the rotor is turning, the device sustains the power to the field winding and generates electricity. Any automotive supply store should be able to give you pricing. The caveat is that you only get 12 - 14V out; this will have to be put through a DC-AC converter to get mains power for running household items.

Comment: A generator that works like this is called a "dynamo".